# Setting numpy array values based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 channel image stored in numpy array.
I want to set some pixels to white if these pixels have red_channel bigger than certain value

what is most efficient way to do this?

Note: image shape is 100×100×3

Thanks

Comment: Please give example of shape of the array, e.g. is the 3 the first or last dimension?

Comment: image shape is 100×100×3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the last dimension is the r,g,b (as for example is the case when using `imageio.imread`) then you would do for example:

```
x = image[:, :, 0] > cutoff
image[x, :] = 255
```

Example:

```
import imageio

cutoff = 200

image = imageio.imread("in.jpg")
x = image[:, :, 0] > cutoff
image[x, :] = 255
imageio.imwrite("out.jpg", image)
```

Comment: .image[..., 0] this is new for m,but what if I want another condition on green channel

Comment: @AnasBari I changed the '...' (probably overkill here to allow for variable number of dimensions because we know the number of dimensions is 3,)  But regarding condition on green channel, `image[:, :, 1]` will be the green, but what condition? You just said red > some value.

Comment: I tried to use this x = a[:,:, 0] > 200 and a[:,:, 1] > 45 but it gives me an error

Comment: Ah, that's because you are using `and`. You need an element-by-element and. You can either use `np.logical_and(a[:,:, 0] > 200, a[:,:, 1] > 45)` or I think `a[:,:, 0] > 200 & a[:,:, 1] > 45`. Just going to test this...

Comment: @AnasBari Nearly as I wrote but brackets are needed because the `&` has too high a precedence `(a[:,:, 0] > 200) & (a[:,:, 1] > 45)`. You can also use the `logical_and` as shown above.

Comment: @AnasBari Hope that's working for you now? Although I'm not going to put anything about the green into my answer because it's not in the question.